# reformat date to have month in words

Tags: command-line, date, text-formatting

Currently my text file looks like this..

```
David   Webb    Box 34 Rural Route 2    Nixa    MO  65714   (417)555-1478   555-66-7788 09-13-1970
Martha  Kent    1122 North Hwy 5    Smallville  KS  66789   (785)555-2322   343-55-8845 04-17-1965
Edward  Nygma   443 W. Broadway Gotham City NJ  12458   (212)743-3537   785-48-5524 08-08-1987
O'Reilly    Baba    123 Torch Ln    Joplin  MO  64801   (417)222-1234   456-65-3211 12-13-1999
Martin Bob  44 Boss Rd  Joplin  MO  64801   (417)888-4565   456-98-1111 01-01-2007
```

the dates are in the 9th field and I want to display them as `January 7, 2017` instead of `01-07-2017` for example.

How should I do that? If using options please explain what they do briefly. Doing this in bash. Needing to put it in a script and output to a new file to preserve original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be easily done via *GNU awk* by its time functions (**mktime** and **strftime**) but *sed* can do this too

```
sed '
    /^[0-9]/{                         #for last field with date
        y|-|/|
        s/^/date +"%B %d, %Y" -d /e   #reformat string by date
        b                             #go to end (print)    
    }
    s/\(.*\)\s/\1\n/                  #separate last field
    P                                 #print string without last field
    D                                 #operate just last field from start
    ' original.file | 
paste - - > new.file
```

Comment: im getting this when i try it... `sed: -e expression #1, char 16: extra characters after command`

Comment: @JonButler Please check sed version

Comment: @JonButler Problem can arise due to comments, so remove second ones as in edited answer

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for bash/shell script, but you could also do this in python if it's available.

```
# date_converter.py
from datetime import datetime
from sys import stdin, stdout

spt = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%m-%d-%Y")
sft = lambda x: datetime.strftime(x, "%B %d, %Y")
convert = lambda x: sft(spt(x))

for line in stdin.readlines():
    stdout.write(line[:-11] + convert(line[-11:-1]) + '\n')
```

Usage:

```
python3.5 date_converter.py < old.txt > new.txt
```

Comment: thank you, i wish i could use python but this has to be strictly bash

Comment: Strictly in bash? You've accepted a sed answer...?