# date is saying invalid date

Tags: awk, date, cut, text-formatting

I currently have a tab delimited text file formatted like this:

```
David   Webb    Box 34 Rural Route 2    Nixa    MO  65714   (417)555-1478   555-66-7788 09-13-1970
Martha  Kent    1122 North Hwy 5    Smallville  KS  66789   (785)555-2322   343-55-8845 04-17-1965
Edward  Nygma   443 W. Broadway Gotham City NJ  12458   (212)743-3537   785-48-5524 08-08-1987
```

I'm trying to format the dates like `September 13, 1970` instead of `09-13-1970`

What I've been trying to do is `cut -f 9 file > tmpfile` and then using

`date -f tmpfile "+%B %d, %Y" > date`

but it keeps saying

```
date: invalid date ‘09-13-1970’
date: invalid date ‘04-17-1965’
date: invalid date ‘08-08-1987’
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is anything preventing you from using one of the solutions you were given earlier? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344705/reformat-date-to-have-month-in-words

Comment: the sed was giving me an error. but i actually just figured it out. for some reason it didn't like having the format in `08-33-1234`. i changed it to `08/33/1234` and then used the `date -f tmp +"%B %d, %Y" > finished` and it worked. interesting

Comment: Local timezone settings probably. In my case it has to be '1970-09-13'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date doesn't accept that input format, try putting year first, such as stream editing the input:

```
cut -f 9 file | sed 's/\(..\)-\(..\)-\(....\)/\3-\1-\2/' > tmpfile
```

Testing by hand:

```
$ date --date '09-13-1970' "+%B %d, %Y"
date: invalid date ‘09-13-1970’

$ date --date '09/13/1970' "+%B %d, %Y"
September 13, 1970

$ date --date '1970/09/13' "+%B %d, %Y"
September 13, 1970

$ date --date '1970-09-13' "+%B %d, %Y"
September 13, 1970
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version using awk, that does not require an intermediate file.

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {FS="\t"; OFS="\t"}
{
    split($9,A,"-");
    S1 = sprintf("%d %d %d 0 0 0",A[3],A[1],A[2])
    D1 = strftime("%B %d, %Y", mktime(S1))
    $9 = D1
    print
}
```